# Testing web applications in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jpa, junit

I have connected a JPA project from Eclipse to MySQL database server. After performing JUnit testing, the tables were created inside my schema but with no rows at all. Do you have any ideas why did this occur in my situation? I have tried refreshing my schema after each JUnit test *(right click on schema + Refresh all)* but still the values were set to null. There are no issues with the JPA code as this has worked for another person using another PC.

EDIT: If you know any good tutorials on webapp testing in MySQL, please do not hesitate to drop them here.

REQUESTED CODE:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/META-INF/spring/crm-core-services.xml" })
public class SpringAppTest {

@Autowired
private CoreService coreService;

@Test
public void CreateProduct_test() {
    Set<DefaultAccount> accounts = new HashSet<DefaultAccount>();
    DefaultProduct product = new DefaultProduct();
    product.setAccount(accounts);
    product.setProductName("CRM-Soft");
    product.setProductPrice(500);
    product.setProductQuantity(100);
    coreService.createProduct(product);
}

@Test
public void CreateCustomer_test() {
    Set<DefaultAccount> accounts = new HashSet<DefaultAccount>();
    DefaultCustomer customer = new DefaultCustomer();
    customer.setWorkField("IT");
    customer.setCompanyName("SolveIT");
    customer.setEmployeesNumber(300);
    customer.SetAccounts(accounts);
    coreService.createCustomer(customer);
}

@Test
public void CreateAccount_test() {
    DefaultAccount account = new DefaultAccount();
    Set<DefaultUser> users = new HashSet<DefaultUser>();
    account.setCustomer(new DefaultCustomer());
    account.setProduct(new DefaultProduct());
    account.setUsername("solve_it");
    account.setUsers(users);
    coreService.createAccount(account);
}

@Test
public void CreateUser_test() {
    DefaultUser user = new DefaultUser();
    user.setAccount(new DefaultAccount());
    user.setAge(30);
    user.setName("Johnny");
    user.setSurname("Bravo");
    coreService.createUser(user);
}

}
```

Comment: Post some of your unit test code.

Comment: Probably your transaction has been rolled back?

Comment: I have added the requested code. Thank you for your responses.

Comment: With null values or with no rows added at all?

Comment: Actually no rows added at all.